# Not able to get geo-cordinates values for few of the addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

For the below 2 addresses, I am not able to generate Geo coordinates. 
I have used 
`var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`
and `geocode function.`

But for other than the below addresses it's generating the proper lat long values.

`37 Rowan Street,ST.JOHN'S,NEWFOUNDLAND` 
`350 TORBAY ROAD,ST.JOHN'S,NEWFOUNDLAND`

Not sure why is this happening.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

I have checked the addresses in the above sample provided by Google also. Its showing the status as `ZERO_RESULTS`.
Can I know why it is not generating the values?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps does not necessarily know all the addresses in the world, you have sometimes to rework your addresses to get something out of the geocoder.

First of all, you should always add the country to your geocoding requests.

In your specific case, it looks like the geocoding works when you remove the street number:

```
Rowan Street,ST.JOHN'S,NEWFOUNDLAND 
TORBAY ROAD,ST.JOHN'S,NEWFOUNDLAND
```

That will be approximate, however. But I don't think you can get any better location here.

Comment: Rowan Street returns a result for Rowan Place, which doesn't seem to have addresses, Torbay Road seems to exist, but also doesn't seem to have addresses.

Comment: Both addresses seem to exist in the Places API Autocomplete database, but don't have locations associated with them (at least from my quick test), this may be a bug in the data.